# natbib: comma after website name

Tags: natbib

Consider the MWE below. The resulting bibliography displays an annoying comma after the website name. Is there any way to fix it (but keep the *unsrtnat* style for all other types like articles)?

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[square,numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{url}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Other{some-web,
  Title                    = {A Website},
  url = {https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page},
 Note                     = {Last visited: 15.03.2014},
}
@Other{some-web2,
  Title                    = {Another Website},
  url = {https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page},
 Note                     = {Last visited: 15.03.2014},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\section{first section}
some content \cite{some-web,some-web2}
\newpage
\section{Bibliography}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The easy solution is to add an `author=...` field.  Oddly, when I do this for one entry, the issue is solved for the other entry as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comma is before the `year`. (When you run `bibtex` on that file you get warnings about "empty year".)

The documentation for `natbib` seems to indicate (in "2.7 Authorless and Yearless References") that that should just be omitted then, but it seems like it doesn't work in all styles.

I would use Biblatex which handles missing fields very well (run `biber` instead of `bibtex`):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=numeric-comp]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{url}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@online{some-web,
  Title                    = {A Website},
  url = {https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page},
  urldate                     = {2014-03-15},
}
@online{some-web2,
  Title                    = {Another Website},
  url = {https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page},
  urldate                     = {2014-03-15},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\section{first section}
some content \cite{some-web,some-web2}
\newpage
\printbibliography[title=Bibliography]
\end{document}
```